# __setup macro not working

Tags: android, c, linux, linux-kernel

I'm trying to modify a module in the linux kernel of my android phone. I'm pretty new with kernel. I read about `__setup()` macro here : http://www.e-reading.ws/chapter.php/101551/103/Hallinan_-_Embedded_Linux_Primer__A_Practical,_Real-World_Approach.html .

And this is my code so far :

```
/* Read cmdline */
static int __init read_cmdline(char *dt2w)
{
if (strcmp(dt2w, "1") == 0) {
    pr_info(LOGTAG"  Enabled. | dt2w='%s'\n", dt2w);
    dt2w_switch = 1;
} else if (strcmp(dt2w, "0") == 0) {
    pr_info(LOGTAG" Disabled. | dt2w='%s'\n", dt2w);
    dt2w_switch = 0;
} else {
    pr_info(LOGTAG" No valid input found. Going with default: | dt2w='%u'\n", dt2w_switch);
}

return 1;
}
__setup("dt2w=", read_cmdline);
```

but when I execute `dt2w=<some int>` I don't see any log output in `dmesg`.
I'm sure that the module is being compiled and loaded because it's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel command line parameters are handled when the kernel is being loaded, i.e., before your module is loaded.

To handle parameters in a module, use module parameters.
(It is still possible to give module parameters on the kernel command line by using something like `mymodule.dt2w=xxx`.)